# How in laravel to add a condition for a eager load relation?

Tags: php, laravel

there are the following models:

```
class Page extends Model {
    protected $with = ['blocks'];

    public function blocks() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Block');
    }
}

class Block extends Model {
    protected $with = ['fields'];

    public function fields() {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Fields');
    }
}

class Field extends Model {
    protected $with = ['data'];

    public function data() {
        return $this->hasOne('\App\Data');
    }
}
```

And there is a controller in which I get the data:

```
public function get() {
    $page_id = 1;
    $data = Page::find($page_id);
}
```

The result is the following structure:

```
Page
    - Block 1
        - field 1
            - Some data
        - field 2
            - More data
    - Block 2
        - Field 1
            - Other data
```

The block may belong to multiple pages.

The field belongs to the block.

But the data stored in this field belong to both the field and the page at the same time.

So, I need to pass the variable $page_id to the data() function of the Field model. To get something like this:

```
public function data() {
    return $this->hasOne('\App\Data')->where('page_id', '=', $page_id);
}
```

Tell me, please, how to do this?

I solved this problem by removing $with from models and selecting the data with this code:

```
Page::with(['blocks.fields.data'=> function($query) use ($page_id){
    $query->where('page_id', $page_id);
}])->find($page_id);
```

But it's not beautiful. I just want to write Page::find($page_id);

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I like force loading relation but in your case maybe this what you looking for :

https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-resources#conditional-relationships

Answer (score 0):

you can do this as the following :

```
Page::whereHas('blocks.fields.data', function($query) use ($page_id){
    $query->where('page_id', $page_id);
})->find($page_id);
```

Comment: it is possible to move whereHas to scope of Data model?

Comment: yes its possible as the following  write this method in model                                                               
                                                                                                      
public function scopePage($query,$page_id)
{
    $query->whereHas('blocks.fields.data', function($query) use($page_id){
    $query->where('page_id', $page_id);
})->find($page_id);
}

Comment: and you can use it Page::page($page_id)->find(page_id);